# Meaning of "potential holds"

Tags: meaning

What does it mean in this context? I saw somewhere the meaning of "dangerous" and the meaning of "keep potential" somewhere else. Which one is correct?

> Richardson (2015) posits that there is significant potential to
>   advance the critical accounting project using quantitative methods. We
>   argue this **potential holds** perhaps even more strongly for critical and
>   non-mainstream SEA research.

Comment: Those are two separate words.  "Potential holds" means nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The word *holds* here is the verb in the relative clause following "We argue."  It means obtains or applies.  *Potential* means possibility.  So

> We argue [that] this potential holds perhaps even more strongly for
>   critical and non-mainstream SEA research.

means that the authors are taking the position (*argue*) that the possibility mentioned in the previous sentence (*this potential*) is even more applicable (*holds ... more strongly*) to SEA research.

Comment: @hamidreza Easy to do.  You might find the sentence "There are three **potential holds** on the President's nominations" in US news articles.